# Why is the javascript if else statement only register reading last else statement?

Tags: javascript, software-lifecycle

The javascript if else statement I am using in LiveCycle is only reading the last else statement and won’t read or recognize the statements that come before it. If you can see what I am missing please help. Here is the code:

```
if (annualUsage.rawValue < 1,000,000) 
{
this.rawValue = annualUsage.rawValue * 0.1;
}
else if (annualUsage.rawValue >= 1,000,000 && annualUsage.rawValue < 10,000,000) 
{
this.rawValue = annualUsage.rawValue * 0.2;
}
else (annualUsage.rawValue >= 10,000,000) 
{
this.rawValue = annualUsage.rawValue * 0.05;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Take the commas out of your numbers? So like

   `if (annualUsage.rawValue < 1000000)`

   etc...
2. Also the last else statement doesn't get a condition so you can
   either remove the condition

   `else{`

   or turn it into an else if statement

   `else if(annualUsage.rawValue >= 10000000){`

Comment: Thanks, removing the comma and addressing the {} on the last statement allowed for the 1st and last statement to be recognized, but...the 2nd middle statement isn't being read?

Comment: Did you remove the comma's from everything first? so all your numbers look like `1000000`? ... also try doing a `console.log(annualUsage.rawValue)` and see what the result is in firebug

Comment: yup it's not reading my (annualUsage.rawValue >= 1000000 && annualUsage.rawValue < 10000000) statement..any ideas?

Comment: First try to `console.log(annualUsage.rawValue)` and see what that spits out because the rest of your statements look fine to me.

Comment: if says that annualUsage is not defined but the other statements work?

Comment: LOL AWESOME I love stuff like that LOL... do you think you could put an example of this up on http://jsfiddle.net/ and get it to break? Then we could go from there.

Comment: I've never used jsfiddle.net does it work with pdf forms? I'm not seeing it. You can see a copy of the pdf here: http://c2intl.com/recquotesheet.pdf

Comment: As you can see in this fiddle your code is correct http://jsfiddle.net/VsW45/ ... by changing the value of `annualUsage.rawValue` you can see teh different results. The issue lies in how that variable is being populated which may be another ticket/question you'll have to make on stackoverflower as this question pertaining to your javascript is `if/elseif` statements are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You're unintentionally misusing the the comma operator.

`a, b` will execute both `a` and `b` and evaluate to `b`.

Therefore, the value you're actually passing to the `if`s is `000`, which is falsy.

---

In addition, the parenthesized expression after the `else` becomes a statement (through ASI) which is the body of the `else` clause.
The `{` after it starts a normal code block which always executes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the comma from the numbers :

   ```
   if (annualUsage.rawValue < 1000000)
   ```

   Otherwise it evaluates to an expression with [comma operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.14).
2. Even the last `else` needs to be corrected.

   ```
   else  if(annualUsage.rawValue >= 10000000)
   ```